# Python не видит установленный ранее модуль: "No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0"

Tags: python, pip

Модуль setuptools-46.0.0 установлен. При попытке установить новый модуль, для которого setuptools является зависимостью, вываливается ошибка что setuptools необходимой версии не найден.

```
[root@tkle-quik0052 ~]#  python3.8 -m site --user-site
/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
[root@tkle-quik0052 ~]# ll /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
total 1876
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:31 cffi
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:31 cffi-1.14.0-py3.8.egg-info
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  810064 Mar 23 09:31 _cffi_backend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      30 Mar 23 10:48 easy-install.pth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     126 Mar 23 10:43 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:04 pip
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:04 pip-19.2.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Mar 23 10:43 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 23 10:43 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:31 pycparser
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 23 09:31 pycparser-2.20-py3.8.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     119 Mar 23 09:04 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    4096 Mar 23 10:43 setuptools
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1052657 Mar 23 10:48 setuptools-46.0.0-py3.8.egg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 23 10:43 setuptools-46.0.0-py3.8.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      30 Mar 23 10:48 setuptools.pth
[root@tkle-quik0052 ~]# python3.8 -m easy_install --version
setuptools 46.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (Python 3.8)

[root@tkle-quik0052 ~]#  python3.8 -m pip install bcrypt-3.1.7.tar.gz
Looking in indexes: http://***/repos/pypi/simple/
Processing ./bcrypt-3.1.7.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1alifztj/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i http://***/repos/pypi/simple/ --trusted-host *** -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (4 lines):
  Looking in indexes: http://***/repos/pypi/simple/
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1alifztj/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i http://***/repos/pypi/simple/ --trusted-host *** -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: pip3.8 list  
Package    Version  
---------- -------  
appdirs    1.4.3  
cffi       1.14.0  
distlib    0.3.0  
filelock   3.0.12  
pip        19.2.3  
pycparser  2.20  
setuptools 46.0.0  
six        1.14.0  
virtualenv 20.0.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то pip install игнорирует в некоторых случаях уже установленные пакеты при установке зависимостей, а так как сервер в закрытой сети, то в инет хода нет.
Решилось распаковкой устанавливаемого архива и установкой

```
python setup.py install
```